# Simplifying $\frac{\pi(1-\cos(\pi x))\cos(\pi x)-\pi\sin^2(\pi x)}{(1-\cos(\pi x))^2}$ to $\frac\pi{\cos\pi x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$
\dfrac{\pi \left( 1-\cos \left( \pi x\right) \right) \cos \left( \pi x\right) -\pi \sin ^{2}\left( \pi x\right) }{\left( 1-\cos \left( \pi x\right) \right) ^{2}}
$$

How can I simplify the above to become the following?

$$
\dfrac{\pi }{\cos \pi x-1}
$$

Comment: Distribute in the numerator then use $\sin(\theta)^2+\cos(\theta)^2=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have,

$\mathsf{\dfrac{\pi(1-cos(\pi\,x))cos(\pi\,x)-\pi\,sin^2(\pi\,x)}{{(1-cos(\pi\,x))}^{2}}}$

$\mathsf{=\dfrac{\pi(1-cos(\pi\,x))cos(\pi\,x)-\pi\big(1-cos^2(\pi\,x)\big)}{{(1-cos(\pi\,x))}^{2}}}$

$\mathsf{=\dfrac{\pi(1-cos(\pi\,x))cos(\pi\,x)-\pi\big(1-cos(\pi\,x)\big)\big(1+cos(\pi\,x)\big)}{{(1-cos(\pi\,x))}^{2}}}$

$\mathsf{=\dfrac{(1-cos(\pi\,x))\big\{\pi\,cos(\pi\,x)-\pi\big(1+cos(\pi\,x)\big)\big\}}{{(1-cos(\pi\,x))}^{2}}}$

$\mathsf{=\dfrac{(1-cos(\pi\,x))\big\{\pi\,cos(\pi\,x)-\pi\,-\pi\,cos(\pi\,x)\big\}}{{(1-cos(\pi\,x))}^{2}}}$

$\mathsf{=\dfrac{-\pi(1-cos(\pi\,x))}{{(1-cos(\pi\,x))}^{2}}}$

$\mathsf{=\dfrac{-\pi}{1-cos(\pi\,x)}}$

$\mathsf{=\dfrac{\pi}{cos(\pi\,x)-1}}$

Comment: is this copied from somewhere?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Where did that font come from?

Comment: @ParthibGhosh because of the font

Comment: Use "\mathsf{}" and write any text

Comment: e.g. $\mathsf{My\,\,name\,\,is\,\,Parthib\,\,Ghosh}$

Comment: Also, $\mathsf{1-tan(\pi\,x)}$  is written using above font